# What is the significance of Chakra of Konark Sun Temple?

Tags: temple

I read about Konark Sun Temple and it makes me proud that about 750 years ago Hindu sages could calculate the accurate time in day and night as well, as they know the weather changes by looking the chakras (wheel of Konark). But unfortunately I can't find out more details about this. I think each chakra in the temple has a lot of meaning and there is more to study. Can anyone point me out to (if there is) full documentation about all chakras in the temple?